# Boot Error: Emask 0X0 SAct 0X0 SErr 0X0 action 0X6 frozen

Tags: linux, sata

Where is this error coming from?
[image]

Comment: I got same error.<br/>
The root cause is the Wake-On-LAN function. See here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1052099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SATA controller gives error messages back for the read and write commands.

The error is timeout, which says that the controller can't communicate with your hard disks, more exactly it doesn't get answer from them.

The most likely cause of the problem is contact problem with your SATA cables. Check with other hard disk, other cable, plug the cable into different slots and so on.